# Database Query only returns column name

Tags: android, database

Hello and thanks for the help!   My database has 4 columns and I need a way to return the newest item added to the last column each time. The column name is spinInterval and the value is an int.

[database http://www.bthindiet.com/datatable.jpg](http://www.bthindiet.com/datatable.jpg)

In my DbAdapter class I have set up a method for retrieving data with

```
 public Cursor fetchReminder(long rowId) throws SQLException {

    Cursor mCursor =

            mDb.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID,
                    KEY_TITLE, KEY_BODY, KEY_DATE_TIME, KEY_SPINNER}, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null,
                    null, null, null, null);
    if (mCursor != null) {
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    return mCursor;

}
```

The code I tried was 
String repeat = RemindersDbAdapter.KEY_SPINNER.toString();  
but all that returned was the name of the column spinInterval.  What would be the correct way to query that info (60 * 60 * 1000 * 8) and would it work each time a new item was added to the db? I am going to add that info to my alarmManager setRepeating call.

```
public class ReminderManager {

private Context mContext; 
private AlarmManager mAlarmManager;



String repeat = RemindersDbAdapter.KEY_SPINNER.toString();

private static final String TAG = "MyActivity";



public ReminderManager(Context context) {
    mContext = context; 
    mAlarmManager = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
}

public void setReminder(Long taskId, Calendar when) {
    Log.e(TAG, repeat);
    Intent i = new Intent(mContext, OnAlarmReceiver.class);
    i.putExtra(RemindersDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID, (long)taskId); 

    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mContext, 0, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT); 

    mAlarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, when.getTimeInMillis(), repeat, pi);
}
```

}

Can anyone help me with the correct code for this?   I am really stuck on it.

Comment: What do you mean "return the newest item added to the last column each time" do you want to sort by date and return the last newest row.. then get the last column value?

Comment: You're not calling your fetchReminder in the code you've provided.. you should be doing that. As well as checking if mDb is not null. If it's null, open the database before querying it.

Comment: I need to sort it by the id number. 3 is the newest one and would need that one now. Next time the user saved a new reminder it would be id 4 and I would need the spinInterval result for row 4 etc.  I have no idea what code to implement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM" + DATABASE_TABLE  +"ORDER BY KEY_ROWID DESC LIMIT 1";
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
```